# Socket server in Java, The last client connected is the only can read the socket

Tags: java, sockets

I have a problem with a socket server that I'm developing.

Firstly, the socket server has then follow class:

- Class `Main_Servidor` (Execute the server)
- Class `EjecutarServidor` (Basically waiting for new connections and then run them as a sub-process)
- Class `ManejoConexion` (receives a socket object from home, and writes and reads in the socket)
- Class `Panel_mensajes` (Shows info about the socket connections in a `jpanel`)
- The client is a little program written in adobe air

The problem is when two or more clients are connected, only the last connected client can read the socket. I've already used the eclipse's debugger for check step by step, but I can't found the error.

Here is my code:

**Main_Servidor Class:**

```
public class Main_Servidor {



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Panel_mensajes PanelMensajes = new Panel_mensajes();
        PanelMensajes.setVisible(true);

        EjecutarServidor ejectuarservidor = new EjecutarServidor();

        ejectuarservidor.ejecutar();

    }

}
```

**EjecutarServidor Class:**

```
public class EjecutarServidor {

    private static final int puerto = 1025;
    private static final int conexionesMaximas = 3;

    private ExecutorService iniciarThread;
    private static ServerSocket listener;
    private static Socket socket;
    private static boolean EsperarConexiones = true;

    public EjecutarServidor()
    {
        //Crea la pila de sub-procesos y se la asigna al objeto iniciarThread 
        iniciarThread = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(conexionesMaximas);
    }

    public void ejecutar()
    {

        Panel_mensajes.MostrarMensaje("ESPERANDO CONEXIONES...\n\n"); 

        try{

            listener = new ServerSocket(puerto); //Esta a la escucha de nuevas conexiones
                                                 //en el puerto especificado.

            GregorianCalendar fecha = new GregorianCalendar(); //Genera la fecha incluyendo la hora

            while(EsperarConexiones){ //Mientras EsperarConexiones sea TRUE esperará por
                                      //nuevas conexiones.
                socket = null;
                socket = listener.accept(); //Acepta la nueva conexión y la asigna a un objeto socket

                //Muesta en pantalla los datos de la nueva conexión
                Panel_mensajes.MostrarMensaje("NUEVA CONEXION " + 
                        socket.getInetAddress().toString().replace("/", "") + ":" 
                        + socket.getPort() + ", "
                        + fecha.getTime() + "\n" + "\n"
                    );

                //Se crea un nuevo objeto ManejoConexion al cual se le pasa como parametro
                //el objeto socket llamado 'socket' que contiene la nueva conexión
                ManejoConexion con_nva = new ManejoConexion(socket);

                //Ejecuta el nuevo objeto ManejoConexion como un nuevo sub-proceso.
                iniciarThread.execute(con_nva);

            }

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Panel_mensajes.MostrarMensaje("IOException en socket!: * " + ioe);
        }
    }

    //Deja de escuchar nuevas peticiones
    public static void cerrarServidor()
    {
        try
        {
            EsperarConexiones = false;
            listener.close();
            socket.close();

        }catch(SocketException SoE)
        {
            Panel_mensajes.MostrarMensaje("SocketException por cerrar servidor, todo OK");
            //SoE.printStackTrace();

        }catch(IOException ioe)
        {
            Panel_mensajes.MostrarMensaje("IOException por cerrar servidor, todo OK");
            //ioe.printStackTrace();
        }finally
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }


}
```

**ManejoConexion Class:**

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ManejoConexion implements Runnable {

    private Socket server;
    private String line;
    private DataInputStream in;
    private static PrintWriter out;
    private static Protocolo proto;
    private static Boolean ACTIVO = true;


    ManejoConexion(Socket server) throws IOException {

        //Recibe un objecto Socket e inicializa la variable server
        this.server = server;

    }

    //Hace que se ejecute un objeto de esta clase como un sub-proceso
    public void run () {

        try {

            //Recibe las tramas de datos desde el servidor
            in = new DataInputStream (server.getInputStream());

            //Envia tramas de datos al servidor
            out = new PrintWriter(server.getOutputStream());

            this.responderPeticiones("+OK");

            //Mantiene abierto el flujo de datos desde el servidor mientras no se cumplan las
            //condiciones.
            Panel_mensajes.MostrarMensaje(Thread.currentThread() + "\n");

            while((line = in.readLine()) != null && !line.equals("TERM")) {

                //Panel_mensajes.MostrarMensaje("CLIENTE " + server.getInetAddress().toString().replace("/", "") + " DICE -> " + line + "\n");
                //proto.entrada(line);

                this.responderPeticiones(line);

                if(!ACTIVO) break;

            }

            this.responderPeticiones("\n" + "CONEXION TERMINADA: " + server.getInetAddress().toString().replace("/", ""));

            Panel_mensajes.MostrarMensaje("\n" + "CONEXION TERMINADA: " + server.getInetAddress().toString().replace("/", "") + "\n" + "\n");
            server.close();

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Panel_mensajes.MostrarMensaje("\nIOException AL RECIBIR PETICION: " + ioe.getMessage());
            //ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    //Se encarga de responder peticiones a los clientes
    public void responderPeticiones(String s) throws IOException
    {
        String input = s;
        String direccion = server.getInetAddress().toString().replace("/", "");

        out.write("SERVIDOR DICE A " + direccion + " -> " + input + "\n");
        out.flush();

    }

    public static void TerminarConexion()
    {
        ACTIVO = false;
        proto = null;

    }

}
```

(I didn't add the `Panel_mensajes` class, because is not much relevant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not easy to understand your code (I guess it's portuguese or spanish). The problem seems to be in `EjecutarServidor`, you have 3 static attributes:

```
private static ServerSocket listener;
private static Socket socket;
private static Boolean EsperarConexiones
```

If a new client connects you simply reset the reference to the client former socket by:

```
socket = null;
socket = listener.accept();
```

This may not work when several clients connect concurrently as the reference to `socket` may break between

```
socket = listener.accept();
```

and

```
ManejoConexion con_nva = new ManejoConexion(socket);
```

Defining `listener` as a static attribute is definitely not a good practive, but should work given your samples. But defining the static `socket` is definitely an error and may lead to unexpected results. You should move the `Socket` declaration into `EjecutarServidor.ejecutar()` like:

```
       while(EsperarConexiones){ 

            Socket socket = listener.accept(); //<-- fix HERE

            Panel_mensajes.MostrarMensaje("NUEVA CONEXION " + 
                    socket.getInetAddress().toString().replace("/", "") + ":" 
                    + socket.getPort() + ", "
                    + fecha.getTime() + "\n" + "\n"
                );

            ManejoConexion con_nva = new ManejoConexion(socket);
            iniciarThread.execute(con_nva);
        }
```

Fix this and see if it changes your app's behaviour.

Comment: I don't know when they became in static. May be I did clic in autofix, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

In your `ManejoConexion` class, you have 3 static variables that shouldn't be. Especially the `PrintWriter`, which will be set to the Socket's output stream of the LAST instance, thus the first instance will suddenly start talking to the last one.

Actually, I'm not sure what `proto` and `ACTIVO` are for, but the `out` static variable should definitely not be static.

Comment: @Guillermo Palafox: You should revisit *all* static variables, they don't seem to make sense at all.

Comment: Jon Lin, Thank you, effectively, the static variables were the problem, I don't know when they became in static. May be I did clic in autofix... bad idea

Answer (score -1):

Pay attention to `private static PrintWriter out;` in ManejoConexion - it should not be static.

Comment: And neither should several other variables. Just changing this one won't fix it.